# Customising django ImageField markup in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a form which allows you to upload an image, but I want to know if it is possible to customise the markup that Django generates.

In the model it is created as an ImageField:

```
logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In the template I am creating an 'upload' form field using

```
{{ form.logo }}
```

This is the markup that gets generated:

```
Currently: <a href="/media/dog.jpg">dog.jpg</a>
<input id="logo-clear_id" name="logo-clear" type="checkbox">
<label for="logo-clear_id">Clear</label>
<br>Change: <input id="id_logo" name="logo" type="file">
```

I want to know if I can change that markup by drilling down further, so that I can for example nest the checkbox to clear the image within its label. I also would like to use my own markup to separate the option to clear the form field from the option to upload a new one. However, I can't find any documentation on how to do this. I've tried outputting

```
{{ logo.logo-clear }}
```

directly but this throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom version of the widget being used in my forms.py: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#ClearableFileInput

```
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput

class CustomImageFieldWidget(ClearableFileInput):
        template_with_clear = '<label for="%(clear_checkbox_id)s">%(clear)s %(clear_checkbox_label)s</label>'

class OrganisationProfileForm(OrganisationCreateForm):

    class Meta(OrganisationCreateForm.Meta):
        widgets = {
            'logo': CustomImageFieldWidget,
        }
```